# Not rotating only one view in a tab bar view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I know this question has been kind of asked and have looked into the solutions that others have posted but still feel quite confused on the topic so I apologize if this really is a "noob" question.

So I have a tab bar view controller and I have 2 views that should autorotate and one that never should. My understanding is that shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation needs to always return YES; in order for any view controllers to autorotate. So if this is the case, how would I get only one to NOT rotate but keep the orders rotating?

Thank you very much!

P.S. I tried this from a different post found here: [How to prevent the view controllers in a tab bar controller from rotating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606066/how-to-prevent-the-view-controllers-in-a-tab-bar-controller-from-rotating)    but with no luck. The answer from that post is posted below

"This is a commonly reported "bug" - however a good workaround is to force the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: selector to be triggered as follows:"

```
   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView *view = [window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[view removeFromSuperview];
[window addSubview:view];
}
```

Comment: Post your `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation ` methods codes. We will check them first =)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I just have shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrienation set to return YES; but before I also had it set to return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);  <--- which resulted in no rotation anywhere.

Comment: Are there more methods that I should involving in this? thanks!

Comment: Nope. Strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're aiming for conflicts with the rotation rules of `UITabBarController`s. You mentioned it yourself:

> shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation needs
>   to always return YES in order for any view controllers to autorotate.

But what you want is for one of the view controllers to return `NO`, which violates that rule. So to answer your question, you will have to implement your own custom view controller container (or a custom view).

There's a good reason this restriction was placed added to `UITabBarController`s. Tabs with different rotation rules will be annoying to user since the screen will keep rotating on them each time they change tabs.

Now if I were you, I'll allow all my tabs to rotate, then present the non-rotating view as a modal view.

Comment: Thank you! But what do you mean by presenting the non rotating view as a modal view? sorry I'm kind of new at this

Comment: Modal views is similar to the concept of "dialogs". You should check out some explanation here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html